# Double object "reuse"

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, lifetime

According to the standard, an object can be transparently replaced.
https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-8

But does it allow it to be replaced more than once and still keep using the old pointer?

Particularly does calling **new (this) C(other)** a second time in the example below still satisfies the following quote from the standard?

> If, after the lifetime of an object **has ended and --->before<--- the storage
> which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is
> created at the storage location** which the original object occupied, a
> pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred
> to the original object, or the name of the original object will
> automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the
> new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if
> the original object is transparently replaceable (see below) by the
> new object

For example, is the following modified example from the standard well-defined?

```
struct C {
  int i;
  void f();
  const C& operator=( const C& );
};

const C& C::operator=( const C& other) {
  if ( this != &other ) {
    this->~C();                 // lifetime of *this ends
    new (this) C(other);        // new object of type C created ( storage re-used after?)
    new (this) C(other);        // new object of type C created again ( storage re-used after again?)!
    f();                        // IS IT STILL well-defined?
  }
  return *this;
}

C c1;
C c2;
c1 = c2;                        // IS IT STILL well-defined?
```

UPD: Technically when calling **new (this) C(other)** a second time, the new object gets created, then the storage location is reused, and then the **original(previous)** object's lifetime ends right? Which is not enough to satisfy https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-8 and hence the code above causes UB? Because the standard clearly says that the lifetime can end when(this "when" I understand at or after) re-using the storage, which implies that re-using storage happens first?

Comment: No, the second placement new does not cause UB. See [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-5) In fact even if the class contained a vector instead of an int, it wouldn't be UB. But it would potentially leave behind unrecovered memory since the destructor wasn;t called. That, however, is not UB. Just really bad programming.

Comment: To clarify my prior comment. There would be no UB if the int were instead a `vector<int>` But it might be if the vector contained objects where lack of a dtor caused UB and not just lack of a ram deallocation.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to asking if leaving out the `this->~C();` from the original example is OK. It depends on the side effects of the constructor/destructor, which are not given. I feel that the standard that you quoted specifically refers to reusing memory of an object whose life-time was ended (meaning, the destructor was called) and therefore says nothing about the case where you omit calling the destructor. Then, since the standard says nothing about it - you could call it undefined; or implementation dependent.

Comment: In practice you can easily argue that if the destructor has no side-effects (that matter) that one can consider it to be called even if you don't call it, in which case the standard says that it is well-defined...

Comment: @CarloWood The placement new "reuses" the storage before the initializer is evaluated. Reuse is one of the allowed preconditions where transparent replacement is allowed. Hence this is neither UB nor implementation defined.

Comment: @CarloWood if the destructor does not have side effects, then doing **new (this) C(other)** would need to end the lifetime, create an object at the location occupied by the previous object, and then "re-use" its storage? Is that really happening? I cannot find a proof for it in the standard

Comment: @doug do you have proof from the standard that the placement new "reuses" the storage before the initializer is evaluated?

Comment: @doug  "The placement new "reuses" the storage before the initializer is evaluated" - I'm sure you are wrong on this as the standard is happy with **this->~C(); new (this) C(other; f()** That can only be valid if the object is created before the old object been re-used!

Comment: @minex Nope. Take a look at [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-1). Example 1 shows exactly that. the the storage is reused before the initializer expression is evaluated. Since the initializer uses the same object that is no longer valid, it's UB!.  Specifically, "When evaluating a new-expression, storage is considered *reused* after it is returned from the allocation function, but before the evaluation of the new-initializer ([expr.new])." from the same link. Note that `other` is still intact. It's evaluated after the storage for `*this` is reused by placement new. Hence not UB.

Comment: @doug yeah but than Example 3 won’t work from their example because object won’t be transparently replaced since the new object would be created after previous object lifetime ended and after its storage was reused

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. It's the word "reuse."  For placement new, reuse refers to the storage, not lifetime. Placement new first "reuses" the storage. This ends the lifetime of the object that was in that storage. Then the placement new initializer expression is evaluated and that starts the lifetime. The lifetime can't be started until the expression is evaluated. Since the prior object has the same type, it is transparently replaced. It's explicitly stated [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-5)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254696/discussion-between-minex-and-doug).

Comment: @doug however for object to be transparently replaced a new object has to be created before the storage has been reused after its lifetime ended. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-8